# Autonumber - specify starting point

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access 2007

I'm trying to start AutoNumber at 5,000 and increase it by 9 for each entry. Is there any way to do this? It doesn't have to be with AutoNumber, if there is another way in Access to do this, that would be great too. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  An auto-number column should be used only to provide a unique index.  It should have no additional semantic meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DDL under ADO to set the autonumber seed and increment.  (However, echoing @mwolfe02's comment ... why?)

```
Dim strSql as String
strSql = "ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourAutoNumberColumn COUNTER(5000, 9)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Also see if this previous Stack Overflow question is useful to you: [How to reset autonumber seed - MS Access/VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290938/how-to-reset-autonumber-seed-ms-access-vb6)

Comment: @ HansUp, the reason why I need to do this is because my boss is requesting it. Other than that, I don't really know. Do you think it would be slightly more logical to apply this to just a number column, as opposed to the AutoNumber column?

Comment: Hmmm.  If it's a regular number, rather than autonumber, you need to come up with a plan to generate (and maintain?) the sequence your boss demands ... that could be challenging.  Will you have to "back-fill" the sequence if a record is deleted, or is there also a requirement that records *never* be deleted?

Comment: No, there isn't a back-fill requirement, so I guess that would make it a little easier to implement. I've actually never touched Visual Basic, but I imagine the code above wouldn't be too hard to execute. Maybe I'm just being optimistic :)

Comment: Have you considered that the in-between values could still be appended? That is, just because you've got 5000, 5009 and 5018 doesn't mean that a SQL INSERT can't insert 5001, 5015 or 4099. Your boss wants to invest meaning in something that shouldn't have meaning and it's going to lead to grief.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of why one would need such a beast.

But you could use a "normal" AutoNumber that starts at 1 and increases by 1 and just show (and use) the computed column:

```
FakeAutoNumber = (AutoNumber * 9) + 4991
```